# Why don't ODataQueryOptions work for both sides of a 1..* relationship?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, odata

I have two tables that are joined by a link table and exposed through OData / Entity Framework:

- USERS
- USERGROUP

Using ~/api/Users, the following `[USER]` API controller action returns results:

```
    public IEnumerable<USER> Get(ODataQueryOptions<USER> options)
    {
        var unitOfWork = new ATMS.Repository.UnitOfWork(_dbContext);

        var users = options.ApplyTo(unitOfWork.Repository<USER>().Queryable
                                              .Include(u => u.USERGROUPS)
                                              .OrderBy(order => order.USERNAME))
                                              .Cast<USER>().ToList();

        unitOfWork.Save();      // includes Dispose()

        return users;
    }
```

I am, however, unable to apply the ODataQueryOptions to the following `[USERGROUP]` API controller action:

```
    public IEnumerable<USERGROUP> Get(ODataQueryOptions<USER> options)
    {
        var unitOfWork = new ATMS.Repository.UnitOfWork(_dbContext);

        var userGroups = options.ApplyTo(unitOfWork.Repository<USERGROUP>().Queryable
                                .Include(u => u.USERS)
                                .OrderBy(order => order.GROUPNAME))
                                .Cast<USERGROUP>().ToList();

        unitOfWork.Save();      // includes Dispose()

        return userGroups.AsQueryable();
    }
```

When I do, I get the following error:

> Cannot apply ODataQueryOptions of 'DAL.USER' to IQueryable of
>   'DAL.USERGROUP'.

Instead, I have to omit the `options.ApplyTo(...)`:

```
        var userGroups = unitOfWork.Repository<USERGROUP>()
                                .Query()
                                .Include(u => u.USERS)
                                .Get()
                                .OrderBy(order => order.GROUPNAME);
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all. You cannot apply a query meant to be applied on a collection of users on a collection of user groups. Change the parameter type to `ODataQueryOptions<USERGROUP>`.

Comment: Too easy.  Missed that.  Thanks.